# How to plot and save it inside a R function in R in mac

Tags: r, macos, plot, lattice

My question is that I want to save a plot inside an overall big function to summarize result. However, when I do not put my plotting command in the big function, it works great, but when I run the big function, then I my plot can not be opened because they are damaged. Is there any options I can achieve my goal? Neither of the two options I provide below works.

Thanks guys!:)

I am using a mac machine with yosemite system
Here is my code:

```
library(lattice)
poissonICARMCMCPost = function(overallRes, preProcessData,path){

####Posterior part#########################################
### get the posterior information from the posterior samples
result = overallRes$result
resultSubset = overallRes$resultSubset
quartz()
acfplot(resultSubset)
dev.copy2pdf(file = paste(path, "acfplot", ".pdf", sep=""))
dev.off()
}
```

I have also tried

```
poissonICARMCMCPost = function(overallRes, preProcessData,path){
####Posterior part#########################################
### get the posterior information from the posterior samples
result = overallRes$result
resultSubset = overallRes$resultSubset
pdf(paste(path, "acfplot", ".pdf", sep=""))
acfplot(resultSubset)
dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Try `print(acfplot(resultSubset))`

Comment: Thanks so much! I add print() to the first solution, it works!!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for MrFlick's great comment, I find a solution that works for now:

```
poissonICARMCMCPost = function(overallRes, preProcessData,path){
####Posterior part#########################################
### get the posterior information from the posterior samples   
result = overallRes$result
resultSubset = overallRes$resultSubset
quartz()
print(acfplot(resultSubset))
dev.copy2pdf(file = paste(path, "acfplot", ".pdf", sep=""))
dev.off()
}
```